# Place link in title from "read more" php WP

Tags: php, wordpress, function, echo

PHP help needed, so I got a wordpress problem I have function that show title content and continue reading text, and I need to place link from continue reading text in title and hide Continue reading text. Here is code from file that generate following title:

```
    function whisper_entry_title2()
{
    if ( !( $title = get_the_title() ) )
        return;

    // Check on singular pages
    $is_single = is_singular() && !is_page_template( 'tpl/blog.php' ) && !is_page_template( 'tpl/blog-boxes.php' );

    // Allow to config via global variable
    if ( isset( $whisper['is_single'] ) )
        $is_single = $whisper['is_single'];

    $tag = $is_single ? 'h1' : 'h2';
    $title = sprintf( '<b class="black">%4$s</b>', $tag, get_permalink(), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), $title );
    echo apply_filters( __FUNCTION__, $title );


}
```

And here is the part of the code that generate continue reading:

```
function whisper_content_limitoffer1( $num_words, $more = '...', $echo = true )
{
    $content = get_the_content();

    // Strip tags and shortcodes so the content truncation count is done correctly
    $content = strip_tags( strip_shortcodes( $content ), apply_filters( 'whisper_content_limit_allowed_tags', '<script>,<style>' ) );

    // Remove inline styles / scripts
    $content = trim( preg_replace( '#<(s(cript|tyle)).*?</\1>#si', '', $content ) );

    // Truncate $content to $max_char
    $content = wp_trim_words( $content, $num_words );

    if ( $more )
    {
        //$event_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'event_id', TRUE);
        //$link="http://example.com/wp/events-offers/";
        $output = sprintf(
            '<p class="event2-cf-oe">%s <a href="%s" class="more-link right o_6" title="%s">%s</a></p>',
            $content,
            get_permalink(),
            sprintf( __( 'Continue reading &quot;%s&quot;', 'whisper' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ),
            $more
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $output = sprintf( '<p class="event2-cf-oe">%s</p>', $content );
    }

    // Still display post formats differently
    $output = whisper_post_formats_content( $output );

    if ( $echo )
        echo $output;
    else
        return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your 'Continue reading' text is being outputted by the line that reads

```
sprintf( __( 'Continue reading &quot;%s&quot;', 'whisper' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ),
```

so just get rid of that line and that text is gone.  Though I suspect you'll probably want to get rid of that entire block of code

```
$output = sprintf(
        '<p class="event2-cf-oe">%s <a href="%s" class="more-link right o_6" title="%s">%s</a></p>',
        $content,
        get_permalink(),
        sprintf( __( 'Continue reading &quot;%s&quot;', 'whisper' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ),
        $more
    );
```

And the link to your post is generated by the line just above that one which reads

```
get_permalink()
```

so you can relocate that.

You can quite easily output the post title and make it a link to the post with these simple Wordpress functions:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title; ?>
</a>
```